# phonegap cordova.js is missing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I use my connected phone as an ADB device.

→ phonegap -v
3.1.0-0.15.0

I have almost nothing in my index.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

When i run

```
→ phonegap local run android  
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] successfully installed onto device
```

I can see my app runing and before did not notice the error in console. Then i tried more complicated things like ngRoute but it did not work. I decided to remove all data to almost empty project as you can see(to be sure something else does not cause this error).

Then i checked the console via:

```
adb logcat | grep -i console
```

And i see:

```
I/Web Console( 3946): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may 

fail.:1511
E/Web Console( 3946): Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined:76
I/Web Console( 4329): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 4329): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 4329): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 5006): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
E/Web Console( 5006): Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined:76
I/Web Console( 5476): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 5949): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
E/Web Console( 5949): Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined:76
I/Web Console( 6374): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
E/Web Console( 6374): Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined:76
I/Web Console( 6762): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 6762): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 7141): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 7141): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
E/Web Console( 7141): Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined:76
I/Web Console( 7267): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 7267): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 7383): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 7383): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 7557): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 7557): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 7697): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 7697): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 7998): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 7998): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
I/Web Console( 8156): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 8156): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
E/Web Console( 8156): Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined:10
I/Web Console( 8491): exception firing pause event from native:1
I/Web Console( 8491): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.:1511
E/Web Console( 8491): Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined:76
```

But it does not makes sence. I have this script tag in my index.html as you can see + this file exists in:

```
platforms/android/assets/www/
```

I also copied this file into my normal www directory.

So what's the problem please?

Comment: how are you calling index.html from the webkit controls?

Comment: Hmm i am not sure what this question mean.

Comment: in your android code, index.html is called in your WebView control. How does your code for this look?

Comment: I still dont know what do you mean. My first day with phonegap. After the successfull compilation of the code(as you can see in question) on the phone the app is launched and i see everything like on desktop browser with styles etc.

Comment: The bug is tracked here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/134

Comment: yes, saw it before but did not find solution workaround there.

Comment: It should be noted that I was getting this error and tried all solutions before realizing it was a random JS error... apparently that can manifest this warning as well.

Comment: You should be able to ignore the error about `cordova.js` as long as `phonegap.js` is generated as well. That is, if you are still using PhoneGap as opposed to Cordova.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by completely reinstall of everything and setting up enviroment back again but now BY CORDOVA TERMINAL COMMANDS not phonegap.

Comment: Interesting, does it function the same as phonegap? Are there other benefits to using cordova over phonegap?

Comment: Idk, i wasn't digging in it anymore... i just know that it definely works now without problems :) so i suggest this way on 100% ... fixed many issues :) If you will experience some problems... let me know i will try to help you.

Answer (score 6):

Try to remove the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

from your `index.html`. If you take a closer look you will see that `phonegap.js` and `cordova.js` are the same size. Apparently `phonegap.js` exists for legacy support reasons, but you should use only `cordova.js`.

This is what it's actually suggested in the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/134) referenced in the comments, and it did the trick for me, I stopped getting the `Could not find cordova.js script tag` message.

Comment: Hm.. i  tried that when i remember good but did not help... but eventually i have figure this out when you check my answer. Thx anyway for your try.

Comment: No problem. At least it worked for me and some other people on the github issue so it may be helpful to someone else.

Comment: This removed the error for me. Cheers. A bit disappointing that the app created by the command phonegap create etc comes with redundant code. Much of the phonegap guides on the official site are also years old, e.g. ios getting started guide is still based on phonegap 2.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the `phonegap.js` with `cordova.js` and it worked, as referenced here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/134#issuecomment-22035314

Remove from `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

and add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```